# Get-Service results to array

Tags: powershell

I'm sure this should be straight forward but I've been stuck on it for a while now...

I am trying to get the service names (for sql server) into an array but can't figure out how to do it. I basically want the array contents to look something like the output of this:

```
Get-Service -computername $server_name -name sql* | format-table -property name
```

I have tried things like this but the contents of $service_name are very odd:

```
$service_name = (Get-Service -computername $server_name -name sql* -exclude *sqlwriter | format-table -property name)
```

Whatever I try either errors or gives some strange message in my array. Should this be easy/possible? I'm guessing I could dump the results in a text file then use the contents of that but it's a bit messy and more overhead than seems necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `format-table` in the pipeline. Anytime you use a `format-*` cmdlet, that's the end of the line for your data - it's now just a formatted bunch of text, it's no longer data that you can actually *use*.

Try this to get the names formatted as a table for viewing:

```
$service_name = (Get-Service -computername $server_name -name sql* -exclude *sqlwriter);    
$service_name | format-table -property name;
```

That said, I ran both your version and mine above and got the same *visual* output - the critical difference is that mine stores data in `$service_name`, not just a bunch of text (as yours does).

edit:

In response to:

> All I really needed was the service names in an array to then use elsewhere

```
$service_name = (Get-Service -computername $server_name -name sql* -exclude *sqlwriter) | select-object -expandproperty name;
```

or:

```
$service_name = (Get-Service -computername $server_name -name sql* -exclude *sqlwriter).name;
```

No need to invoke WMI directly.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I have now found a solution like this: 
$service_name = (Get-WMIObject -computer $server_name -class Win32_Service -Filter "Name LIKE '%MSSQL$%'" | select-object name).name
All I really needed was the service names in an array to then use elsewhere so your way also works I think
Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but where you looking for this (with whatever variation on the pattern for `-Name` and/or `-Exclude`)?

```
PS> $names = (Get-Service -Name Sql* | select name)
PS> $names.GetType().IsArray
True
PS> $names.Length
3
PS> $names

Name
----
SQLBrowser
SQLSERVERAGENT
SQLWriter
```

Or even along the lines of the following if you really want the "Name" as a `System.String` array.

```
PS> $names = (Get-Service -Name Sql* | foreach { $_.Name -as [string]})
PS> $names[0].GetType().FullName
System.String
PS> $names
SQLBrowser
SQLSERVERAGENT
SQLWriter
```

But also keep the good advice in @alroc's answer in mind - maybe you want to keep the actual type of `Get-Service`'s result (`System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController`) as long as possible and access/use the `Name` property of it as late as possible. YMMV.